# Drop down Menu not going to transverse

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I need help with dropdown menu

I wanted to make dropdown menu to transverse (see image below)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/etEeB.jpg]

but mine the dropdown menu goes bottom.

[image]

here is the code : (template from yootheme_balance)

```
/*
Function: process

  Returns:
    Object
    */  
    public function process($module, $element) {

  foreach ($element->find('ul.level2') as $ul) {

    // get parent li
    $li = $ul->parent();

    // get columns
    $columns = (int) $li->attr('data-menu-columns');

    if ($columns > 1) {

    $children = $ul->children('li');
    $colrows  = ceil($children->length / $columns);
    $column   = 0;
    $i        = 0;

    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $col = intval($i / $colrows);

        if ($column != $col) {
      $column = $col;
        }

        if ($li->children('ul')->length == $column) {
      $li->append('<ul class="level2"></ul>');
        }

        if ($column > 0) {
      $li->children('ul')->item($column)->append($child);
        }

        $i++;
    }

    } else {
    $columns = 1;
    }

    // get width
    $width = (int) $li->attr('data-menu-columnwidth');
    $style = $width > 0 ? sprintf(' style="width:%spx;"', $columns * $width) : null;

    // append dropdown divs  
    $li->append(sprintf('<div class="dropdown columns%d"%s><div class="dropdown-bg"><div></div></div></div>', $columns, $style));
    $div = $li->first('div.dropdown div.dropdown-bg div:first');

    foreach ($li->children('ul') as $i => $u) {
    $div->append(sprintf('<div class="width%d column"></div>', floor(100 / $columns)))->children('div')->item($i)->append($u);
    }
  }

  return $element;
    }

}
```

Comment: Make a fiddle of your code !

Answer (score 0):

use css for `<li>`..as below:but only for parent li not the child

```
li{display:inline-block;}
```